# Excel VBA: I record macro with scatter plot that executes x, f(x), but when I run macro, always plots X and F(x) as separate functions

Tags: excel, excel-2007, scatter-plot, vba

Like I said, I have a set of data, just a simple x column and then an f(x) column that is a function. When I record my macro, I simply select x, f(x) and the twenty values below for each column, select scatter plot and it outputs the graph I want, with f acting as a function of x.

When I go to run the macro, it always outputs a scatter plot but instead of graphing f(x) as a function of x, it justs plots both sets of numbers as independent series. I can't figure out how to change it.

Here is my code:

```
Sub insertGraph()
'
' insertGraph Macro
'

'
Range("A4:B25").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet5'!$A$4:$B$25")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ChartType` before you set the `SetSourceData`

Whats happening is that `AddChart` and or `SetSourceData` creates a chart of the default type (Column) which has no X-axis data, so plots columns A and B as two series.  Changing to Scatter retains these two series.

You should also avoid using `Select` (the recorder is good for finding out what objects to use, but creates terrible code!).  Here's how:

```
Sub insertGraph()
    '
    ' insertGraph Macro
    '
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType:=xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Chart
    With cht
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("A4:B25")
        ' add additional code to set other properties of the chart...

    End With
End Sub
```